# Convert time_t to little endian?

Tags: objective-c, endianness

I am converting `NSDate` to Unix time. Problem is, I need to convert this to little endian so that it can be sent over Bluetooth; but I have no idea how to convert `time_t` to little endian.

**What I have so far:**

```
time_t t = [date timeIntervalSince1970];

NSMutableData * date = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[data appendBytes:&t length:sizeof(t)];
```

**What I get:**

```
0x10603854 // Fri, 15 Sep 1978 21:02:12 GMT
```

**What I need:**

```
0x54386010 // Fri, 10 Oct 2014 22:39:12 GMT
```

Comment: Isn't this a plain old C question?

Comment: (Looks to me like you already have little-endian.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not the most elegant way.

```
NSMutableData *time_ = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
time_t t = [date timeIntervalSince1970];
[time_ appendBytes:&t length:4];

unsigned char *bytePtr = (unsigned char *)[time_ bytes];
NSString* _time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X%02X", bytePtr[3], bytePtr[2], bytePtr[1], bytePtr[0]];

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    if (_time.length > i*2)
    {
        byte_chars[0] = [_time characterAtIndex:i*2];
        byte_chars[1] = [_time characterAtIndex:i*2+1];
        whole_byte = strtol(byte_chars, NULL, 16);
        [data appendBytes:&whole_byte length:1];
    }
}

NSLog(@"_time_data %@", _time);
```

### Output:

> 2014-10-13 16:54:59.766 wrightscs[20810:2929687] _time_data <543c4a31>

### Timestamp Converted:

> Hex time: 543c4a31
>
> GMT: Mon, 13 Oct 2014 21:54:57 GMT
>
> Your time zone: October 13, 2014 at 4:54:57 PM CDT
>
> Decimal timestamp/epoch: 1413237297

http://www.epochconverter.com/epoch/unix-hex-timestamp.php

Comment: Although this method worked for me and that I will continue to use, @dreamlax answer is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to ensure endianness of a particular value is to use the `NSSwapHostXYZToLittle` or `NSSwapHostXYZToBig` (where `XYZ` is the type). More information about these functions can be found [at this Foundation Functions reference page](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIBBDHJ).

I think for OS X and iOS, `time_t` is a `long`, so you want to use `NSSwapHostLongToLittle` if you want to guarantee that the value is little-endian. To convert back, you use `NSSwapLittleLongToHost`. Similarly, if you are converting to big-endian, you can use `NSSwapHostLongToBig` and to convert back, you can use `NSSwapBigLongToHost`.

These functions become a no-op if you are already executing code on little-endian architecture.

```
time_t t = NSSwapHostLongToLittle([date timeIntervalSince1970]);
NSMutableData *date = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
[data appendBytes:&t length:sizeof(t)];
```

Comment: This is much cleaner, and in fact, I had my question backwards, should have been Big, so `NSSwapHostLongToBig` returns the correct format for me.

Comment: On iOS and Mac OS X `time_t` is an `int64_t` which would be a `long` on 64 bit platforms or a `long long` on 32 bit platforms.

Comment: @CuriousRabbit: I'm not sure that's true, printing `sizeof(time_t)` when compiling with `-arch i386` gives `4`, not `8`, indicating it is likely still just a `long` or possibly just `int`.

Comment: Yep, I'm wrong. It's a `long` on both. I.E., 32 bits on 32 bit architectures and 64 bits on 64 bit architectures. Thank you for the correction. I'm not sure where my mistaken assumption came from, but I'll not forget it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are communicating over Bluetooth, then presumably there's a device on the other side that has some fixed requirements, like "4 byte, little endian, seconds since 1970". You need to write the code in terms of that device. If your code runs on a 64 bit system, then time_t is unlikely to be a 32 bit number, but the device you are talking to doesn't know that and still expects 32 bits.

You should look up how little endian numbers are stored, and then write code that puts four bytes in the right order into your NSData.